# Google Speech-To-Text: How to Speed Up (General Advise)

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am planning to use Google Speech-To-Text to transcribe around 14,000 radio shows (.flac files with one channel), each around 15 Min long. All data was uploaded to a Google Storage Bucket. I planned to transcribe the shows via the API, but given the around 145 days of content, obtaining the information would take more than a month.

I was wondering: *are there any ways to speed up the process, i.e. to send parallel requests or similar?*

I'm a newbie to Google Cloud services, so any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd certainly expect you to be able to make multiple requests, configuring each operation to write the results back to Google Cloud Storage. I'd be most concerned about quota at that stage.

Comment: Thank you! I do have the funding to make the requests, i.e. quota should not be an issue (?). Would that work by running multiple API-client via a local python script in parallel or are there better ways? E.g. directly via Google's Console? Any links to useful resources would be very helpful

Comment: Quota and funding aren't the same thing. There can be quota limits applied (unless you request them to be lifted) - I suggest you check the docs carefully for that. You shouldn't need to create multiple API clients for this - you could use a single client to create multiple long-running requests. Your code to create those requests can then just finish, so long as you've configured the result to be uploaded to GCS. See https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#upload_your_transcription_results_to_a_bucket

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas for quota limits. (Note that you can request higher quota limits...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jonskeet, you can create multiple long running requests using  client library and store the results in GCS bucket following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#upload_your_transcription_results_to_a_bucket).

With regards to quota and limits, since your input audio is in GCS there is no size limit on requests. However, you will have to look into Google Speech-to-Text API's `request limits`  mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#request_limits) for quota limits.